# response is undefined in jasmine unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

test case

```
it('SaveVersionMainScreen', fakeAsync(() => {
        let response = comp.SaveVersionMainScreen();// return undefined instead of false
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(response).toEqual(false);
    }));
```

This is my component method which is tried to test

```
SaveVersionMainScreen() {
        let element = this.commonValidation(true);// return null
        if (element) {            
            return false;
        }else{
          return true  
        }
     }
```

When i running my test case, the `this.commonValidation(true)` returns null. So the if condition is passed `true` and `SaveVersionMainScreen()` is returning `false`. But I am getting `undefined` in  my test case.

`let response = comp.SaveVersionMainScreen(); //  response is undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason. But when i use return in out side of the if & else statement, then it's working fine

```
SaveVersionMainScreen() {
        let element = this.commonValidation(true);// return null
        if (element) {            
            return false;
        }else{
          return true  // here i have some logic's.
        }
       return true
     }
```